# How to UTF8 encode a signed xml file without BOM preamble in c#

Tags: c#, xml, encoding

I have a function that sign my xml file, the file it's in utf-8 encoding but when i apply the sign it show me "utf-8 with Boom" (wrong version), how can i save the file correctly

```
private static void FirmarDocumentoComplemento(string pathXmlDocument, string pathCert, string passCert, string pathXmlSignet, string ruta, string rut, string fecha, string tipo)
{

    XmlDocument documentXml = new XmlDocument();
    documentXml.Load(pathXmlDocument);

    SignedXml firmado = new SignedXml(documentXml);

    var cert = RSA_helper.GetX509Certificate(pathCert, passCert);
    firmado.SigningKey = (RSA)cert.PrivateKey;
    firmado.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1";

    //digest info
    Reference reference = new Reference();
    reference.Uri = "";
    reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1";

    firmado.AddReference(reference);

    // with the public key will be added in the signature part. 
    KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
    keyInfo.AddClause(new RSAKeyValue((RSA)cert.PrivateKey));
    keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(cert));

    firmado.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
    firmado.ComputeSignature();

    XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = firmado.GetXml();

    // buscamos el ultimo elemento del documento para agregarle la firma
    XmlElement elemento = (XmlElement)documentXml.SelectSingleNode(@"//datos_complementarios_declaracion_ingreso/representantes[last()]");

    XmlNode parent = elemento.ParentNode;
    parent.InsertAfter(xmlDigitalSignature, elemento);


    string ruta_completa = ruta + rut + " - " + tipo + " - " + fecha + " - N - " + "Complemento Firmado.xml";
    documentXml.Save(ruta_completa);

}
```

Comment: Are you using following : https://github.com/smart-on-fhir/xml-bundle-uploader/blob/master/package-lock.json  It appear it is using a tgz (zip) file and may be the error is due to wrong version of the zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your document using an [XmlTextWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextwriter?view=netframework-4.8)'s instance passing at its constructor an [XmlWriterSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings) instance where you explicitly set the **Encoding** property to an instance of [UTF8Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.utf8encoding) without the BOM preamble

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
string ruta_completa = $"{ruta}{rut} - {tipo} - {fecha} - N - Complemento Firmado.xml";

XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ruta_completa, settings);
doc.Save(writer);
```